# How to process command with && (and) as parameter?

Tags: bash

In my script I want to proceed first argument as necessary file name and all other arguments as shell commands separated by `&&` (and operator).

```
echo "${@:2}"
```

But Bash cuts all commands except first one.

How to fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while inotifywait -q -e close_write -e delete $1; do "${@:2}"; du app; done;
```

```
./watch . g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app
```

Comment: Please make an example and put some more code.

Comment: What?! Could you give an example?

Comment: while inotifywait -q -e close_write -e delete $1; do "${@:2}"; du app; done;

./watch . g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app

Comment: @AlexUshakov And what is the problem, exactly? What do you expect to happen, and what happens?

Comment: What you need to understand in bash is `$0` (script file name), `$1` (first arg), `$2` (second arg)... When you use `${@:2}` you are using all arguments beginning with `$2` (e.g. `$2`, `$3`, ...). That is how bash works. I am still unclear on what your goal is in your `while inotifywait...` line.  Also, what is the numerical `return` from `inotifywait`? If it is any positive number, the `while` loop will exit. (`0` - true, `#` - false in bash)

Comment: Script must compile, show execution time and ready binary size. But it only compiles.

Comment: @AlexUshakov You do know that you're only executing your script with five arguments (`.`, `g++`, `app.cpp`, `-o` and  `app`), right? The rest of that line is handled by Bash, and will be executed *after* the script.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app`. That should be working fine. (I'll have to lookup what `watch` contributes. How exactly are you calling your script?

Comment: Is there any way to avoid problem? Maybe I should use getopt?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `./watch . g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app` or `./watch . "g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app"`

Comment: @AlexUshakov What? What *is* ‘the problem’?

Comment: I use inotifywait utility for looking on abstract sources directory. When it detects any change it must do several things. For example, compile and launch, etc. The question is - how to make script (it will be stored in directory in $PATH) that will look at necessary directory (first agrument) and do necessary things (all other arguements) separated by &&.

Comment: @AlexUshakov If you want to send `&&` to the script you'll have to quote it.

Comment: https://asciinema.org/a/4akup5zog5xh00rkys9ot53m7

Comment: this dont work `./watch . command0 && command1`

Comment: @AlexUshakov Of course it doesn't. The *unqouted* `&&` is parsed and used by Bash.

Comment: My mistake. I mean `./watch . "command0 && command1"`

Comment: @AlexUshakov As for the film, it looks like you're trying to execute the rest of the arguments as a single command, since you quote `${@:2}`. Hence the ‘`g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app: No such file or directory`’. Remove the quotes or use `eval` or something. But [be careful](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

Alex, I get the jest of what you are attempting to do with `inotifywait`, but when I attempted it, it would just hang and do nothing as the files were static at the point it was called. Looking at what you are attempting to accomplish. (build, run, measure disk usage of `app`) it may be easier to just script it instead of putting `inotifywait` in the middle of it.

While this is just a basic hack at getting the output you wanted. The script below will take the source file as the first argument (`app.cpp` by default if no name given) and will compile the code using the name before `.cpp` as the g++ output file name. It is a simple attempt to get the information you were looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

src=${1:-app.cpp}   ## set the source and output (exe) names
out=${src%.cpp}

printf "\n compiling 'g++ %s -o %s'\n\n" $src $out

[ -f $out ] && rm $out      ## remove existing exe before builinding

g++ $src -o $out            ## build new exe

[ -f $out ] || {            ## validate new exe created
    printf "error: compilation failed. exiting script.\n\n"
    printf "usage:   %s source.cpp (default: app.cpp)\n\n"
    exit 1
}

[ -e $out ] || {            ## validate it is executable
    printf "error: file produced from compilation is not executable.\n"
    exit 1
}

time ./$out 2>&1                        ## compute elapsed time
exesz=$(du -h $out | awk '{print $1}')  ## store disk usage (removing name)

## print results
printf "\n Source file:  %s\n" "$src"
printf " output file:  %s\n" "$out"
printf " size of exe:  %s bytes\n\n" "$exesz"

exit 0
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./watch.sh

 compiling 'g++ app.cpp -o app'

Code Running
and being timed.

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s

 Source file:  app.cpp
 output file:  app
 size of exe:  16K bytes
```

The test code I used was a simple `cout`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    cout << "Code Running" << endl << "and being timed." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Incorporating iowaitnotify**

Understanding better what you are attempting to accomplish, below is an addition (without all the validation checks) that will watch your source file and recompile on any change. It also avoids the use of `eval`. There are several ways to accomplish this, this being one. You can add the validation checks from the script above if you desire:

```
#!/bin/bash

bldcmd=( ${@:2} )   ## array for build command

while inotifywait -q -e close_write -e delete $1; do 
    echo -e "\ncompiling:  ${bldcmd[@]}"
    # eval "${@:2}"
    ${bldcmd[@]}
    time ./app
    printf "\n app size: %s\n" $(du -h app | awk '{print $1}')
done
```

**Output**

```
$ ./watch . g++ app.cpp -o app
./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE app.cpp

compiling:  g++ app.cpp -o app

Code Running (ver. 6)
and being timed.

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s

 app size: 16K
```

Comment: Thank you for big reply. Your script, as I understand, dont look at changes like inotifywait. And there is small error ` line 24: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'`. And what mean `store disk usage (removing name)`?

Comment: Sorry, the missing `)` was the result of an accidental backspace. I've also added a way to use an array to avoid `eval` in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've read the question correctly, but I think you're asking how to `watch` a pipeline, i.e. repeatedly run `g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app`.  If that's what you need to do, you must quote `&&` so it's not interpreted by your (top-level) shell, but instead by the shell that `watch` invokes:

```
watch g++ app.cpp -o app '&&' time ./app '&&' du app
```

You could of course use backslash escaping (`\&\&` instead of `'&&'`) if you prefer.

Comment: Just realised you're not using `/usr/bin/watch`, but a script of your own called `watch` - that changes things.

Comment: Perhaps an explicit sub shell?  `./watch . bash -c 'g++ app.cpp -o app && time ./app && du app'`

Answer (score -1):

Solution is `eval` command     .

Comment: glad you found it, but be aware it can have side-effects. I don't think they are applicable here.

Comment: Can you explain - what side effects do you mean?

Comment: Sure see [**Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include more information (e.g. an example of *how* you used the `eval` command).